# Highcharts - Change color of hover points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

So, I've bene looking at the highcharts API, for an option to change the color of the point background color, when hovering the chart.

This is my current chart: **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gwdufurk/)**

And the code:

```
$(function () {
            $('#main-chart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'area'
                },
                plotBorderColor: '#000000',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#000000',
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Clicks'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        pointStart: 1940,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            radius: 2,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'USA',
                    lineColor: '#4adefa',
                    color: '#f1faf7',
                    data: [251, 122, 511, 424, 291, 426, 121, 342, 110, 235, 369, 640,250]


                }, {
                    name: 'USSR/Russia',
                    lineColor: '#44d99f',
                    color: '#f1faf7',
                    data: [215, 125, 450, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 900, 340, 429]
                }]
            });
        });
```

When hovering the chart, the "point marker" is a round gray circle - I want to change that to be a round circle with a white background and green border.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post the theme object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your `plotOptions` if you want the style of the points to be the same for every series.

```
              marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fillColor: 'white',
                                lineColor: 'green',
                                lineWidth: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

A working fiddle can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gwdufurk/3/

If you want to have the styles of the points to be different for each series you can set the `marker.states.hover` attributes for each series like so:

```
 series: [{
                name: 'USA',
                lineColor: '#4adefa',
                color: '#f1faf7',
                marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                fillColor: 'white',
                                lineColor: 'green',
                                lineWidth: 0
                            }
                        }
                    },
                data: [251, 122, 511, 424, 291, 426, 121, 342, 110, 235, 369, 640,250]
               // other series here.

            }
```

See fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gwdufurk/4/.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the markers like so:

```
...  
marker: {
    fillColor: 'green',
    ...
```

Edit: [Fiddle with red markers](http://jsfiddle.net/gwdufurk/2/)

Comment: Can you have a different marker color, for each series?

Comment: Yes, put the marker configuration into each of the series, like so: `... series: [{ name: 'USA', marker: { fillColor: '#f00' }, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Different Marker Color for Hover Pointer,

```
 data: [
                         { name: 'Point 1',color: '#4adefa', y: 251 }, 
                        { name: 'Point 2',color: '#000000', y: 122 },
                        { name: 'Point 3',color: '#A25429', y: 511 },
                        { name: 'Point 4',color: '#AA1111', y: 524 },
                        { name: 'Point 5',color: '#DF2500', y: 291 },
                        { name: 'Point 6',color: '#007ACF', y: 342 },
                        { name: 'Point 7',color: '#ECD66E', y: 110 },

                       ]
```

See fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/gwdufurk/5/